# React Native Fetch API In IOS Only Semicolon In Url Not Encoded

Tags: ios, react-native, url, fetch-api, encode

So I'm using React Native for an IOS App, and using Fetch API for networking. My URL is like this:

```
https://example.testing.com/filterString=product.code><CODE01;CODE02
```

and it's usually automatically encoded after I call the fetch method. It's supposed to be like below for my App to get the response correctly from the server:

```
https://example.testing.com/filterString=product.code%3E%3CCODE01%3BCODE02
```

But instead it become like this:

```
https://example.testing.com/filterString=product.code%3E%3CEKWED014T;EKWED014
```

So it won't encode ONLY the semicolon part of the url.

Here's my code:

```
const response = await fetch(url, { method, headers });
```

And here's how I found that my url isn't encoded correctly after being sent to the server:

```
const responseURL = await response.url
console.log('displayUrl: '+responseURL);
```

**UPDATE:**

I need to add that there is no option to encode the url before calling the "fetch" method, because it will still get encoded again, so it will get encoded twice.

For example, I encode just the semicolon:

```
"CODE01;CODE02" to "CODE01%3BCODE02"
```

The method would just pick the "%" and then it become:

```
"CODE01%253BCODE02"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `encodeURIComponent` method to ensure your url is encoded correctly on both iOS and Android.

```
 const const baseUrl = 'https://example.testing.com/filterString=';
 const encodedProducts = encodeURIComponent('product.code><CODE01;CODE02');
 const url = baseUrl + encodedProducts;
 console.log(url) //results in https://example.testing.com/filterString=product.code%3E%3CCODE01%3BCODE02
 const response = await fetch(url, { method, headers });
```

Comment: I did tried this yesterday, so if I encode the url first, then call "fetch" method with it, the url would get encoded again, so it gets encoded twice, So, if the original is "CODE01;CODE02", instead of "CODE01%3BCODE02", it became "CODE01%253BCODE02"

Comment: it will works fine on android though